# How to add style sheet with images in .NET Core + Angular2 solution

Tags: angular, .net-core, styles

I have been working on project, where I am building a web portal using .NET Core + Angular 2. IDE is VS 2015.
The components and setup works fine. I have used Webpack for client build. My solution structure looks as below:

[image: Solution Structure]

What I am stuck now is this external lib has images and stuff referred in CSS files in the library. I want to use images in the library in my component HTML. As in the screenshot below.

[image: Image code and refereed Image]

Can some one help me how can I use the image, as for now I am getting error 500 error for image link

Comment: Unless webpack knows about the wwwroot directory and you have a plug-in configured to load images, you need to serve that from a different path like `/lib/assets/images`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to serve files from above the web root. Try an absolute path starting from `/lib`.

Essentially change `../../../../wwwroot/lib/assets/x` to `/lib/assets/x`.

You could also use `../../../lib/assets/x` but I would prefer an absolute URL as it is more maintainable as, should you happen to move the referencing file, you won't have to update the path.